# uniqueness of solutions of $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ in a semigroup .

Tags: semigroups

Suppose $G$ is a semigroup in which every equation of the form $ax=b$ or $ya=b$ has a solution. Does this solution have to be unique?

Comment: yes/no answer, probably with a link, can suffice.

Comment: Does this solution or do these solutions??

Comment: @BabakS.: I mean if there's a unique solution for ax=b for fixed a and b.

Comment: If $G$ is finite then your answer is yes.

Comment: well I think there's an answer in the link suugested as duplicate of this question.

Comment: @CrossChris: You mean, you fixed a and b or you make them free wandering the set? Indeed, you can find a semigroup in which for just some fixed "a" and "b" ax=b has different solutions.

Comment: @BabakS.: The complete statement is in the duplicate suggested: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/346661/93637

Comment: @Bill Cook: This is not a duplicate, since in the question the uniqueness is not required.

Comment: The other question is a different question, but it does have an answer to this one there. Nevertheless, I'm voting to re-open because I think someone searching for this question will not find that one.

Comment: This question does not have two key points of information: the context in which the question was encountered (what class? what book?) and, just as important, what you have already tried. If the question is reopened, it should be edited to include these things.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I wanted a yes/no answer. that piece of info does not need trying. because I'm not gonna try and read any proof. just yes/no. + cclear math question does need context. '*Hey what time is it?*'  '*oh first say where do you want to use that time. Is your class late? will your boss blame you? what's the context  to ask this question. Have you tried to listen to a radio, radio says the time, what have you tried? In future give me more info OK, now get lost*'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$x$ has to be $a^{-1}b$ and $y$ has to be $ba^{-1}$. They are unique of course.

Comment: Elements in a semigroup are not necessarily invertible (in fact, there might not even be an identity element).

Comment: sorry for my carelessness, I misread it as "group". Extremely sorry again!

Comment: @Rebecca: Why did you delte your own??

Comment: The result at the link is much better than what I wrote.

Comment: @Rebecca: I found the counter example and wanted to refer to yours.

Comment: I'm confused, a counter-example?  Is Henning Makholm's proof incorrect?

Comment: @Rebecca: Nope! Infact the counter example you noted as a contradiction. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the counter example @Rebecca noted. In fact, we see that in some cases we don't find any solutions and this happens cause there are more than one solutions in other case.

```
  gap> a:= Transformation([2, 3,3]);;
       b:= Transformation([ 3,2,3]);;
       s:= Semigroup(a, b);;
       e:=Elements(s);;
       for k in [1..3] do
           for j in [1..3] do
              for i in [1..3] do
              if e[j]*e[i]=e[k] then Print("k:=", k,"   ", "j:=",j, "   ",i,"\n"); 
              fi;
              od; 
           od;
        od;

        k:=1   j:=1   2
        k:=2   j:=2   2
        k:=3   j:=1   1
        k:=3   j:=1   3
        k:=3   j:=2   1
        k:=3   j:=2   3
        k:=3   j:=3   1
        k:=3   j:=3   2
        k:=3   j:=3   3
```

Comment: Now this really needs a TU! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Good time, Amy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If a semigroup has a left identity and any element has a left inverse, then it is a group (Hall M.,The theory of groups).

Your semigroup has these properties. Indeed, let $ea=a$ and $ax=b$. Then $eb=eax=b$, so $e$ is a common identity.