# Understanding step in proof of semi-group with equations $a \ast x = b$ and $x' \ast a' = b'$ admitting solutions for any a, b, a', b' is a group

Tags: group-theory

I do not understand one point in the proof from user68061 of this [statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656881/proving-that-g-is-a-group-if-ax-b-and-ya-b-have-solutions)

There is a similar question ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346595/prove-that-g-circ-is-a-group-if-a-circ-x-b-and-x-circ-a-b-have-uni#new-answer)) but this time with no unicity condition for the solutions x and x'.

Henning Makholm provided an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/346661/38057) but I do not understand his first statement:

If e and a are given such that ea=a, then e is a left identify for every element. Proof: Given b let x be such that ax=b. Then eb=eax=ax=b.

What he says is really this:
$$\forall a \forall b \exists x (b = a \ast x) \text{(hypothesis: $a \ast x = b$ admits a solution)}$$
$$\forall e \forall a \forall b \exists x (e \ast b = e \ast ( a \ast x )) \text{(binary operation allows left multiplication by a same element e)}$$
$$\forall e \forall a \forall b \exists x (e \ast b = ( e \ast a ) \ast x) \text{(associativity)}$$

At this point we would need to use $\exists e \forall a ( e \ast a ) = a$ in order to move to the next step, but this is precisely what you want to show!

Can someone provide a formal proof of that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewording Henning Makholm's statement, we want to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a set with an associative binary operation $*$ such that for all $a,b \in G$, there is some $x \in G$ such that:
>   $$
> a * x = b \tag{$\star$}
> $$
>   Now suppose that there exists some $e \in G$ and that there exists some $c \in G$ such that $e * c = c$. Then for all $d \in G$, we know that $e*d = d$.

**Proof:** Choose any $d \in G$ and suppose that there exists some $e,c \in G$ such that:
$$
e * c = c \tag{1}
$$
Now take $a = c$ and $b = d$ so that (using $(\star)$) there exists some $x \in G$ such that:
$$
c * x = d \tag{2}
$$
Then observe that:
\begin{align*}
e*d &= e * (c * x) &\text{by substitution via $(2)$}\\
&= (e * c) * x &\text{by associativity}\\
&= c * x &\text{by substitution via $(1)$}\\
&= d &\text{by substitution via $(2)$}\\
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$