# To prove set is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Given a non empty set  together with associative binary operation $*$ on $G$ such that

$a*x=b$ and $y*a=b$ have solutions in $G$ for all $a,b$ in $G$

To prove it is a group

Hints to get started

Thanks

Comment: In other words: "An associative [quasigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) is a group".

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346595/prove-that-g-circ-is-a-group-if-a-circ-x-b-and-x-circ-a-b-have-uni/346661#346661) (which has an additional assumption that the solutions for $x$ and $y$ are _unique_, but not all answers require that).

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following equations have solutions for **every** $a$ and $b$ :
$$\begin{align} ax&=b\tag{R_1(a,b)}\\
 xa&=b \tag{R_2(a,b)} \end{align}$$

Given an arbitrary element $a$, let $e$ be a solution of $ax=a$ (solution of $R_1(a,a)$). Then for any $b$ there exists $y$ such that $ya=b$ (use $R_2(a,b)$), hence $be=yae=ya=b$. So $e$ is a right unit. Given an arbitrary element $t$ the equation $tx=e$ (use $R_1(t,e)$) has always solution, so $G$ has a right unit and every element has a right inverse. Then it is a group.

Comment: Beat me to it! $\,$

Comment: @Elaqqad shouldn't that be $ax=b$ in first line

Comment: why it should be $ax=b$?

Comment: Don't we also need to prove that $G$ is closed under the operation?

Comment: @Elaqqad it is given in question

Comment: @K. Dutta Since $a,b$ are arbitrary, you can choose both of them to be the same object.

Comment: @Elaqqad I am finding this convincing ,i dont know is their any other method

Comment: @Uzman: the question says "binary operation $*$ on $G$" -- this wording implies an assumption that the output of the operation is always in $G$.

Comment: @Elaqqad You have taken first $b=a$ and then $b=e$  ???

Comment: @K.Dutta yes for the first one I took $b=a$ and after that I used the second equation and to prove that any element has a right inverse I took $b=e$

Comment: @Elaqqad Isn't that a contradiction  showing identity is not unique

Comment: @K.Dutta, (I did not really understand why it should be not unique , sometimes you must explain more by showing where the contradiction comes) In the answer there is no contradiction, we defined $e$ and if you consider that an another element $e'$ verify the same assertions then we can prove that $e=e'$ (in fact the first thing we can prove in a group is there is only one unit)

Comment: @Elaqqad i meant why b=a=e ,doesn't show that identity is not unique ?

Comment: @K.Dutta can you read the solution now ,in fact they are not the same $a$ and $b$, you have a solution which is true for every elements $a$ and $b$ and I used it for some elements

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed, thanks.